# Bootstrap carousel using ajax

Tags: jquery

I need a bootstrap carousel-like layout with 16 buttons in each slide. I am accumulating the data through ajax call.
If I have 32 items from the DB the 16 should be as the first slide and the next 16 should be the next slide. Current problem is that all the buttons are appearing in the same slider.

```js
success:function(data){
                        len = data.length;
                        txt = '';
                        $('#subitemsection').html(txt);
                                    
                      var count = 1;
                   
                       for(i = 0 ; i<data.length ; i++) {
                             if (count%16 == 1){
                                    var txt1=  '<div class="carousel-item">'
                                    $('#subitemsection').append(txt1);
                                }
                               var txt2 = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary sub-item-section-btn" value=""><h5 class="item-font">'+"Hi"+'</h5></button>'  
                                $('#subitemsection').append(txt2);                                
                               
                            if (count%16 == 0){
                                     var txt3 = '</div>' 
                                $('#subitemsection').append(txt3);
                                    }
                            count++;
                            
                        }
                             if (count%16 != 1){ 
                              var txt4 = '</div>'
                                $('#subitemsection').append(txt4);

                               }
                    },
```

I tried the current code.But the carousel  is closing before the button.
[image]

Comment: can you please create a sample plunker/jsbin and share here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve the problem . it will be helpful for others

```js
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (count % 20 == "1") {
    if (count == "1") {
      txt1 = '<div class="carousel-item active">';
    } else {
      txt1 = '<div class="carousel-item">';
    }
    append += txt1;
  }

  txt2 = '<button type="button"></button>";
  append += txt2;

  if (count % 20 == "0") {
    append += txt3;
  }
  count = count + 1;
}

if (count % 20 != 1) {
  txt4 = "</div>";
  append += txt4;
}

$("#Targetid").append(append);
```